# Cannot find component ID: gs:// (...)

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to work on a component but I get the following error message when I try to add my component in Google Data Studio:

> Cannot find component ID: gs://(....)

What is the best way to debug this issue?

In the console I noticed there is a resource with a `500 error`.

```
The response is :
)]}'
{"errorStatus":{"code":13}}
```

The url is:
https://datastudio.google.com/getCommunityVizRegistrationInfo?hl=en&appVersion=20190131_01020013

In the payload there is onyly the vizId that contains the gs URL of the component.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is now solved. I simply forgot to make the objects publicly readable.
The component is now properly loaded.